# Not being able to configure Timezone gem

Tags: google-maps, timezone, ruby-on-rails-5

Trying to configure lookup from the timezone gem;

https://github.com/panthomakos/timezone

I get a 403 when I use google configuration

I am adding this code:

```
 Timezone::Lookup.config(:google) do |c|
   c.api_key = 'your_google_api_key_goes_here'
   c.client_id = 'your_google_client_id' # if using 'Google for Work'
 end
```

To a file in initializers called timezone.rb and I I see on google dev cloud Time Zone API  is enabled , and I have restarted the application

I am getting:

```
*** Timezone::Error::Google Exception: 403 Forbidden
```

when I try:

```
 Timezone.lookup(-34.92771808058, 138.477041423321)
```

Comment: Stupid question: you're using an actual API key/client id, right?

Comment: The same I am using for geocoder, how can I verify is the correct one?